# Window schedule task to run as admin with GUI

Tags: windows, powershell

In windows, I want to schedule tasks to run as admin. The app has GUI.
Is it possible to evaluate the user group so it will run the app as admin?

the user is already apart of the admin group.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to tick ["Run with highest privileges"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XK8M.png)?